# How can i prevent the NOW function from update everytime and automatically? Is there a way to do that?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I got a sheet where I want to put the actual date on column "B1" only when I insert some text on column "A1". I did that using the IF and NOW formula but, as you may know, the date is automatically updated everytime and I want to prevent that (I dont want the date to be updated unless I edit "A1")

Is there a way to do that? Utilizing a script or something like that?

Thank you all everybody!

(I expect once the data is on the cell, it wont be updated anymore.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.range.getSheet().getName()!='SomeSheetName') {return;}
  if(e.range.columnStart==1 && e.value.length>0) {
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM dd,yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
  }
}
```